# Sql Query through ComboBox does not return any record

Tags: sql, combobox

I am using `Sqlconnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` wizard to make a simple query following the Query Builders in Visual Basic 2015. DsQuery1 is the DataSet. My SQL Statement looks like:

```
SELECT [Record ID], Ser, [Project ID], [Time From], [Time To], Speed, [Veh Count]
FROM   Àctual
WHERE ([Project ID] = 'cbProjectID.SelectedText')
```

`cbProjectID` is a form combo box data binded to another Table name "Project_info" and field name [Project ID]. I have placed a datagrid to show the result. But always 0 records are returned whereas i am sure that there are records to be returned.

My vb.net code for a search button is :

```
Try
    Using SqlConnection1
        If SqlConnection1.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SqlConnection1.Open()
            MsgBox("Connected!")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Connected!")
        End If

        SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DsQuery1.Àctual)

        ÀctualDataGridView.DataSource = DsQuery1.Àctual.DefaultView

        MsgBox(DsQuery1.Àctual.Rows.Count)

    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I am locked up for two days. But could not make any headway. I need assistance. In this case if i would use the parameterrized query then how do i define the value of parameter to the combobox text in the Query Wizard of Sql DataAdapter. What will be the syntax in VB Net 2015.

Regards and Thanks

Tariq

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you to avoid using characters with accents in code/DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the parameter should cbProjectID.selectedvalue if I understood your questions correctly